# Is it possible to have <script type="text/javascript"> inside of a php class?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

if so.. how is it done? I know it's probably a stupid question but I'm uncertain on how it's done. This script below:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
$('charge_amt').keyup(function(){
    var that = this;
    $('#charge_cc').prop('checked', function(){
        return that.value.length;
    });
}); 
});
</script>
```

How do i integrate it into this class:

```
class OkToShipEDPump extends \Komment
    {
    /**
        Declare any autofill data.
        */
    protected function my_data()
        {
        }

    /**
        Declare all fields applicable to this comment, with any display options.
        */
    protected function my_fields()
        {
        $help = new FieldHelp($this->patient);
        return array(
            input_group('Call Type'
                ,input_select('call_type'
                    , array('NC'=>'OK - NO CHANGES'
                        ,'IN'=>'OK - PENDING INS'
                        ,'PI'=>'OK - PENDING INS/PO'
                        ,'PO'=>'OK - PENDING PO'
                    ), 'NC', 1)->label(' ')->reason_swap()
                )->left()
            ,input_group('Copay and Credit Card', 
                input_text('copay', 20)
                ,input_check('charge_cc')
                ,input_text('cc_amt', 20)->label()->mand()
                )->right()
            ,input_group('Please fill in info'
                ,input_hidden('category', 'OK')
                ,input_text('spoke_to', 30, 'PT')->mand()
                ,input_date('ship_date', date("n/j/Y"))->reason_show('call_type', 'nc')
                )->left()
            ,input_group('ED Supply'
                ,input_select('ed_pump',ptdme('L7900'), '', 1)->label('ED Pump ')->mand()
                )->right()
            ,input_group('Additional Notes',
                input_tbox('additional_notes', 3, 80, 250)->label()
                )->whole()
            );
        }
```

I put it at the end of the class after the closing php tags but it didn't work. I suppose that's be cause it has to be called before the actual fields.

Any and all help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: you could as PHP is just rendering html/text content. If there is js script inside, it'll be interpreted as usual by the browser. Don't ask me how, PHP give me headhache

Comment: The entire page is just a php class rendering input boxes and running functions. I'm trying to use the keyup function to mark the box as checked if data has been entered into the input. ,input_text('cc_amt', 20)->label()->mand()    -----Hope that helps.

Comment: Ya, but js MUST be interpreted client side. What i told you is to echo js script from php depending of how do you want to handle it server side and then auto call this script on the client (browser)

Answer (score 2):

You can't "execute" javascript in your class, per se, but you can include it in your page by simply echoing it...

```
<?php
  ...

  echo <<<JS
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
      $('charge_amt').keyup(function(){
        var that = this;
        $('#charge_cc').prop('checked', function(){
          return that.value.length;
        });
      }); 
    });
    </script>

  JS;

  ...
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Under usual circumstances, JavaScript is supposed to be executed client-side (in-the-browser), and PHP is supposed to be executed on the server-side.

You can have JavaScript Code in PHP as content of a text var, in order to send it to the browser for local execution.

e.g.

```
<?php
    $jsInject = '<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">alert("o hai");</script>';
    print($jsInject);
?>
```